# how to provide expression to `purrr::pmap` for function using tidy evaluation

Tags: r, purrr, rlang, tidyeval

I am trying to write a function using `rlang` so that I can subset data based on supplied expression. Although the actual function is complicated, here is a minimal version of it that illustrates the problem.

## minimal version of needed function

```r
library(rlang)

# define a function
foo <- function(data, expr = NULL) {
  if (!quo_is_null(enquo(expr))) {
    dplyr::filter(data, !!enexpr(expr))
  } else {
    data
  }
}

# does the function work? yes

head(foo(mtcars, NULL))     # with NULL
#>                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#> Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1

head(foo(mtcars, mpg > 20)) # with expression
#>                 mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4      21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Datsun 710     22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> Merc 240D      24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
#> Merc 230       22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
```

## problems with `purrr::pmap`

When used with `purrr::pmap()`, it works as expected when `expr` is `NULL`, but not otherwise. Instead of `list`, I also tried using `alist` to supply the input.

```r
library(purrr)

# works when expression is `NULL`
pmap(
  .l = list(data = list(head(mtcars)), expr = list(NULL)),
  .f = foo
) 
#> [[1]]
#>                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#> Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1

# but not otherwise
pmap(
  .l = list(data = list(head(mtcars)), expr = list("mpg > 20")),
  .f = foo
)
#> Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
#> ℹ Input `..1` is `"mpg > 20"`.
#> x Input `..1` must be a logical vector, not a character.
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Can you use `expr = list(quote(mpg > 20)))` in `pmap` instead of a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to make this work is by wrapping with `quote`

```
purrr::pmap(
  .l = list(data = list(head(mtcars)), expr = list(quote(mpg > 20))),
  .f = foo
)
```

-output

```
[[1]]
                mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4      21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710     22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
```

which also works with the `NULL`

```
pmap(
  .l = list(data = list(head(mtcars)), expr = list(quote(NULL))),
   .f = foo
 ) 
[[1]]
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Same output with `subset`

```
subset(head(mtcars), mpg > 20)
                mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4      21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710     22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
```

---

Or another option is to modify the function by changing the `enexpr` to `parse_expr`

```
foo1 <- function(data, expr = NULL) {
  if (!quo_is_null(enquo(expr))) {
    dplyr::filter(data, !!parse_expr(expr))
  } else {
    data
  }
}
```

-testing

```
> pmap(
+   .l = list(data = list(head(mtcars)), expr = list(NULL)),
+   .f = foo1
+ ) 
[[1]]
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1

> 
> pmap(
+   .l = list(data = list(head(mtcars)), expr = list("mpg > 20")),
+   .f = foo1
+ )
[[1]]
                mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4      21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710     22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
```

Comment: I _can_ do this, and that would work. But this will be a user-facing function and, if possible, I don't want them to have to  use `quote`, which will be quite mysterious for the newbies. I will wait to see if there are any other solutions provided that don't require quoting. If not, I'll accept yout answer :)

Comment: @IndrajeetPatil the issue would be that you are using `enquo` in your function.  Probably, `ensym` may work (not tested)

Comment: Using `ensym` gives the following error when `expr` is `NULL`: `Error: Only strings can be converted to symbols`

Comment: @IndrajeetPatil with you function, you may change the `enexpr` to `parse_expr` when you pass strings

Comment: @IndrajeetPatil the only drawback is that you have to provide the input as string for expr in both cases `head(foo1(mtcars, "mpg > 20"))`